# asp.net calender control

Tags: asp.net

I have used calender control in asp.net2.0, which on clicking of a image is openining in other window... with javascrupt window.open form... problem is on local environment is working fine...
but when deployed on server.. after opening image it showing The resource cannot be found. 
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
 /Calender.aspx

i mean when its working in local.. how come its not working on server..

Answer (score 0):

As the HTTP 404 is saying: the resource has not been found at the location you are expecting it to be.

Check if the Calendar.aspx page is actually present on the server.

- If it is, see why the link to that page is wrong in that environment.
- If it isn't, check what has gone wrong with the deployment to the server

Comment: for every question its giving does not match quality standards